# Fluent NHibernate local mdf file doesn't keep table structure

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mdf

i have set up my database with **Fluent NHibernate** and SQL Server, and it was working fine with **SQL Server**. Everytime I execute the code, the database structure was created and data inserted throw the application interface was working perfectly. If I shut the program, the database and the content would stay saved.

I don't want the database in the SQL server, I want the database to be a *.mdf file in the solution file structure. So i can just copy the application without installation process.

The problem, and the reason of this topic, is that using the file in the solution file structure, the application works perfectly while running, but when i close the application the data is all gone. If i start the application again, the data I've inserted is gone.

My class is the following for the SQL Server:

```
class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
                InitializeSessionFactory();

            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
                .ConnectionString(@"server=MyComputer;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=true;")
                .ShowSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyEntity>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(true, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

For the local file, i just change the **ConnectionString** line:

```
.ConnectionString(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="+AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+ "General\\Data\\MyDatabase.mdf" + ";Integrated Security=True;")
```

To commit/persist data to the database I use the following structure:

```
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {

                var newEntity = new EntEntity
                {
                    //Data to populate

                };

                session.SaveOrUpdate(newEntity);
                transaction.Commit();

                if (transaction.WasCommitted)
                {
                    MessageAndCleanInterface("Sucessful created!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Does anyone knows why this happens? 
At this moment, i don't mind to use another type of database type, I will start to make tests with other types.
Nevertheless, I would like to know the reason for this.

Comment: Did you use transactions for your inserts?

Comment: With this line `new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(true, true)` in the `SessionFactory` creation code, your going to get a clean schema every time your `SessionFactory` is created. You don't need to do this every time?

Comment: @Rabban I have edited my post to answer better your question. Resuming, yes, I start the transaction inside the session object and make the commit in the end.

Comment: @DavidOsborne This line is ok. It checks the current schema and will update it if the entity definitions differ from from the schema. It will never delete any data.

Comment: @DavidOsborne I try to execute first time with the code **new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(true, true)** then, after i comment the line and start without it, the database does not work. I cannot insert and I cannot read. For what I read around the **SchemaExport** is the one that clears the data everytime.

Comment: For some reason the data does not persist on the file not managed directly with the SQL Server.

Comment: Did you tried to start your app from .exe file? it could be that vs overwrites your file everytime you start to debug.

Comment: @Nuno Sure. Sorry, I misread it.

Comment: @Rabban, I just build my solution to release version, and as an application, the data is persisted. That solved this question. Thanks so much. Please answer to the question so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @DavidOsborne, no problem :) thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio overwrites your .mdf with every build. If you start only your .exe file without building new, your data should be persisted.